# Kubernetes CKAD Preparation Question: Exposed port is not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

This is what i am trying to do:Get nginx pod's ip created in previous step, use a temp busybox image to wget its '/'

Find the link for your reference:
https://github.com/dgkanatsios/CKAD-exercises/blob/main/a.core_concepts.md#get-nginx-pods-ip-created-in-previous-step-use-a-temp-busybox-image-to-wget-its-

Now my question is when I run this command it works:

```
kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --rm -it --restart=Never -- wget -O- $(kubectl get pod nginx -o jsonpath='{.status.podIP}:{.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort}')
```

but when I do this it does not work. Cam someone explain me why is that ?

```
kubectl get po -o wide # get the IP, will be something like '10.1.1.131'
# create a temp busybox pod
kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --rm -it --restart=Never -- wget -O- 10.1.1.131:80
```

Comment: When you say "it does not work", what happens?  Why are you looking up a pod IP address (you'd normally use a Service's DNS name)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to first create an Nginx pod. This is what is referred as "previous step".

```
$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --restart=Never --port=80

pod/nginx created
```

You can then run wget inside a BusyBox pod:

```
$  kubectl run BusyBox --image=busybox --rm -it --restart=Never -- wget -O- $(kubectl get pod nginx -o jsonpath='{.status.podIP}:{.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort}')

Connecting to 10.42.0.52:80 (10.42.0.52:80)
writing to stdout
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
-                    100% |********************************|   615  0:00:00 ETA
written to stdout
pod "busybox" deleted
```

Comment: why do we need to add --port=80 for the container port when creating the pod? i tested nginx pod without --port=80 in the 1st command and i could wget from busybox pod.